# managed Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a managed lightning component within my salesforce org. I am able to see the managed lightning component inside my lightning component list. But when I try to use it inside global action the managed lightning component is not listing. Do anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The problems can be due to not proper [interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces.htm) provided by the vendor .

For the lightning component to appear in the quick actions you will need an interface named `force:lightningQuickAction`

Comment: This is my 1st line in the  component<aura:component controller="arema_Controller" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >